# Anonymous classes, private methods, and reflection

Tags: java, reflection, anonymous-class, private-methods

If I create an anonymous class with a private method, and try to access the method using reflection, it will throw an IllegalAccessException. However, if I call the method  on the object before saving it to a variable, it works fine:

```
public class Z {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Object obj = new Object(){private void foo(){}};            
        obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("foo").invoke(obj); // throws IllegalAccessException

        new Object(){private void foo(){}}.foo(); // works
    }
}
```

What's the reason for the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you're trying to access the method by reflection, and since it is a private method, the reflector class cannot invoke it, thus it throws an `IllegalAccessException`.

In the second case, you're accessing the method directly, and you're allowed to since because it is an anonymous inner class to `Z` and you're accessing it inside `Z` class.